# RxJava OutOfMemory run-time crash unable to create thread

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-android

I am making network call using Retrofit2+RxJava+RxAndroid.

I have tried with different **`Schedulers`** likewise **`io()`** and **`newThread()`**. I am aware about consequences for using `newThread()` but still application is closing cause of OOM.

Scenario:

- Filter List (65 items after filtering)
- Download gzip from URL
- write bytes and store in realm

above network call occurs 65 times.

code:

```
/*form version download method*/
public void startFormDownload(List<Form> form, ApiClient apiClient) {
    Observable.fromIterable(form)
            .concatMapIterable(Form::getFormVersions) // get form version list from single form object
            .doOnSubscribe(disposable -> AppLogger.i(tag, "Form Versions download is subscribed")) // subscribe process to rx
            .filter(this::checkFormVersionToDownloadOrNot) // only get those versions who needed to downloaded
            .doOnNext(formVersion -> { // get formVersion object

                AppLogger.i(tag, "download this form ---------> " + formVersion.getFormUrl());
                AppLogger.i(tag, formVersion.getFormUrl());
                String constructURL = formVersion.getFormUrl();

                /* download form gzip process starts from here */
                apiClient.getJsonByFormURL(constructURL)
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .subscribe(new SingleObserver<Response<ResponseBody>>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSubscribe(Disposable disposable) {
                                AppLogger.i(tag, "gzip download ->" + "subscribed");
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Response<ResponseBody> responseBodyResponse) {
                                AppLogger.i(tag, "gzip downloaded " + " success");
                                AppLogger.i(tag, "gzip downloaded ->" + responseBodyResponse.toString());

                                if (responseBodyResponse.code() == 401) {
                                    //not authorized
                                    return;
                                }

                                ByteArrayInputStream bais = null;
                                if (responseBodyResponse.body() != null)
                                    try {
                                        bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(responseBodyResponse.body().bytes());

                                        GZIPInputStream gzis = new GZIPInputStream(bais);
                                        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(gzis);
                                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader);

                                        String readed;
                                        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                                        while ((readed = in.readLine()) != null) {
                                            stringBuilder.append(readed);
                                        }

                                        baseRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
                                        formVersion.setJsonString(stringBuilder.toString());
                                        baseRealm.executeTransaction(realm ->
                                                baseRealm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(formVersion));



                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        AppLogger.e(tag, "gzip extract exception->" + e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
                                    }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
                                AppLogger.e(tag, "gzip failed->" + throwable.getMessage(), throwable);
                            }
                        });


            })
            .doOnTerminate(() -> AppLogger.i(tag, "Form Versions terminated"))
            .doOnError(Throwable::printStackTrace)
            .subscribe(
                    formVersion -> AppLogger.i(tag, "Form Versions download completed"),
                    throwable -> AppLogger.e(tag, throwable.getMessage(), throwable)
            );
}
```

There may be case of `InputStream` to cause OOM but I am not sure what can be done here.

PS. OOM occurs only sometimes, not always.

> Crash report

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Could not allocate JNI Env
at java.lang.Thread.nativeCreate(Native Method)
at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:730)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:941)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.ensurePrestart(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1582)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.delayedExecute(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:313)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.schedule(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:550)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.submit(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:651)
at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.NewThreadWorker.scheduleActual(NewThreadWorker.java:146)
at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.NewThreadWorker.schedule(NewThreadWorker.java:51)
at io.reactivex.Scheduler.scheduleDirect(Scheduler.java:135)
at io.reactivex.Scheduler.scheduleDirect(Scheduler.java:111)
at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleSubscribeOn.subscribeActual(SingleSubscribeOn.java:37)
at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:2779)
at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleObserveOn.subscribeActual(SingleObserveOn.java:35)
at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:2779)
at com.visualogyx.app.fragments.VisualogyxBaseFragment.lambda$startFormDownload$10$VisualogyxBaseFragment(VisualogyxBaseFragment.java:623)
at com.visualogyx.app.fragments.VisualogyxBaseFragment$$Lambda$9.accept(Unknown Source)
at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableDoOnEach$DoOnEachObserver.onNext(ObservableDoOnEach.java:95)
at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFilter$FilterObserver.onNext(ObservableFilter.java:52)
at io.reactivex.internal.observers.DisposableLambdaObserver.onNext(DisposableLambdaObserver.java:58)
at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFlattenIterable$FlattenIterableObserver.onNext(ObservableFlattenIterable.java:111)
at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFromIterable$FromIterableDisposable.run(ObservableFromIterable.java:98)
at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFromIterable.subscribeActual(ObservableFromIterable.java:58)
at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10910)
at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFlattenIterable.subscribeActual(ObservableFlattenIterable.java:44)
at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10910)
at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableDoOnLifecycle.subscribeActual(ObservableDoOnLifecycle.java:33)
at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10910)
at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFilter.subscribeActual(ObservableFilter.java:30)
at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10910)
at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableDoOnEach.subscribeActual(ObservableDoOnEach.java:42)
at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10910)
at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableDoOnEach.subscribeActual(ObservableDoOnEach.java:42)
at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10910)
at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableDoOnEach.subscribeActual(ObservableDoOnEach.java:42)
at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10910)
at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10896)
at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10825)
at com.visualogyx.app.fragments.VisualogyxBaseFragment.startFormDownload(VisualogyxBaseFragment.java:683)
at com.visualogyx.app.fragments.VisualogyxBaseFragment.updateJobAndDownloadCheckListForm(VisualogyxBaseFragment.java:239)
at com.visualogyx.app.fragments.VisualogyxBaseFragment.lambda$null$1$VisualogyxBaseFragment(VisualogyxBaseFragment.java:221)
at com.visualogyx.app.fragments.VisualogyxBaseFragment$$Lambda$15.test(Unknown Source)
at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableAllSingle$AllObserver.onNext(ObservableAllSingle.java:69)
at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFromIterable$FromIterableDisposable.run(ObservableFromIterable.java:98)
at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFromIterable.subscribeActual(ObservableFromIterable.java:58)
at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10910)
at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableAllSingle.subscribeActual(ObservableAllSingle.java:34)
at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:2779)
at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:2765)
at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:2686)
at com.visualogyx.app.fragments.VisualogyxBaseFragment.lambda$storeAndRetrieveListFromDB$2$VisualogyxBaseFragment(VisualogyxBaseFragment.java:226)
at com.visualogyx.app.fragments.VisualogyxBaseFragment$$Lambda$0.execute(Unknown Source)
at io.realm.Realm.executeTransaction(Realm.java:1394)
at com.visualogyx.app.fragments.VisualogyxBaseFragment.storeAndRetrieveListFromDB(VisualogyxBaseFragment.java:200)
at com.visualogyx.app.fragments.HomeFragment$1.onSuccess(HomeFragment.java:59)
at com.visualogyx.app.fragments.HomeFragment$1.onSuccess(HomeFragment.java:54)
at com.visualogyx.app.controller.ApiCallback.onResponse(ApiCallback.java:36)
at com.visualogyx.app.controller.ApiClient$11.onResponse(ApiClient.java:264)
at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:70)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6293)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1065)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:926)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to move realm transaction related operation in `doFinally()` block.
so far so good.

```
Observable.fromIterable(form)
            .concatMapIterable(Form::getFormVersions) // get form version list from single form object
            .doOnSubscribe(disposable -> AppLogger.i(tag, "Form Versions download is subscribed")) // subscribe process to rx
            .filter(formVersion -> formVersion.getJsonString() == null) // only get those versions who is not downloaded yet
            .doOnNext(formVersion -> { // get formVersion object

                AppLogger.i(tag, "download this form ---------> " + formVersion.getFormUrl());
                AppLogger.i(tag, formVersion.getFormUrl());
                String constructURL = formVersion.getFormUrl();

                /* download form gzip process starts from here */
                apiClient.getJsonByFormURL(constructURL)
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .subscribe(new SingleObserver<Response<ResponseBody>>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSubscribe(Disposable disposable) {
                                AppLogger.i(tag, "gzip download ->" + "subscribed");

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Response<ResponseBody> responseBodyResponse) {
                                AppLogger.i(tag, "gzip downloaded " + " success");
                                AppLogger.i(tag, "gzip downloaded ->" + responseBodyResponse.toString());

                                if (responseBodyResponse.code() == 401) {
                                    //not authorized
                                    return;
                                }
                                // You should determine it based on response header.

                                if (responseBodyResponse.body() != null)
                                    try {
                                        gzipBody = null;

                                        gzis = responseBodyResponse.body().byteStream();
                                        ungzippedResponse = new GZIPInputStream(gzis);
                                        reader = new InputStreamReader(ungzippedResponse, charset);
                                        writer = new java.io.StringWriter();

                                        buffer = new char[10240];
                                        for (int length = 0; (length = reader.read(buffer)) > 0; ) {
                                            writer.write(buffer, 0, length);
                                        }
                                        gzipBody = writer.toString();

                                        formVersion.setJsonString(gzipBody);
                                        AppLogger.i(tag, "set json string ->" + gzipBody);

                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        AppLogger.e(tag, "gzip extract exception->" + e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
                                    }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
                                AppLogger.e(tag, "gzip failed->" + throwable.getMessage(), throwable);
                            }
                        });


            })
            .doOnTerminate(() -> AppLogger.i(tag, "Form Versions terminated"))
            .doOnError(Throwable::printStackTrace)
            .doFinally(() -> {
                baseRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
                baseRealm.executeTransaction(realm ->
                        realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(form));
            })
            .subscribe(
                    formVersion -> AppLogger.i(tag, "Form Versions download completed"),
                    throwable -> AppLogger.e(tag, throwable.getMessage(), throwable)
            );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use bytestream instead of byte[]

```
String body = null;
String charset = "UTF-8"; // You should determine it based on response header.

try (
    InputStream gzippedResponse = responseBodyResponse.body().byteStream();
    InputStream ungzippedResponse = new GZIPInputStream(gzippedResponse);
    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(ungzippedResponse, charset);
    Writer writer = new StringWriter();
) {
    char[] buffer = new char[10240];
    for (int length = 0; (length = reader.read(buffer)) > 0;) {
        writer.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    body = writer.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have modified my code as per above and I need to test this feature for couple of days if I don't get OOM then i will accept this answer. +1 though.

Comment: I am facing this error `AppData::create pipe(2) failed: Too many open files` for above solution

Comment: one more thing need to change in your code baseRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance(); keep it out from loop so it instantiate only once

Comment: That won't work because i have subscribed on new thread and Realm cannot access from that thread. thats why i have added that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should add log to different part of your code and find out the memory foot print, which part eat the memory. Or you can use AndroidStuido memory alloc tool to monitor the memory allocate.